# GA4のFilterExpressionListに渡せる数に上限はありますか？

Tags: google-analytics-api

phpからGoogle Analytics Data APIを利用してデータを取得しようとしています。

このように`FilterExpressionList`でデータは取得できていますが、`expressions`の要素数が400件ほどになる可能性があります。
`expressions`に渡せる数に上限はありますか？
もしない場合、だいだいこれくらいに抑えておけば大丈夫だろうという数はありますか？

```php
$response = $client->runReport([
    ...(省略)...
    'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
        'or_group' => new FilterExpressionList([
            'expressions' => [
                new FilterExpression([
                    'filter' => new Filter([
                        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                        'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => MatchType::FULL_REGEXP,
                            'value' => '/hoge.*'
                        ])
                    ])
                ]),
                new FilterExpression([
                    'filter' => new Filter([
                        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                        'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => MatchType::FULL_REGEXP,
                            'value' => '/fuga.*'
                        ])
                    ])
                ])
            ]
        ])
    ])
]);
```